# Change a shapefile with grids to a 2D grid world for RL

Tags: python, coordinate-system, shapefile, grids-graticules, 2d

I have a shapefile with multiple grids as polygons. I want to convert this into a 2D gridworld so that I can train an RL agent. I tried different libraries but I am stuck in the part of brain storming.

This is the image of the shapefile containing multiple polygons as grids.

[image: Img of shapefile]

I want to convert this into a 2D gridworld to train an agent.

I used rasterio to convert this into a binary grid but it did not work properly. I am using Python for this task.

The size of the grids inside the shapefile must be equal to the grids in the grid world.  How should I change this into a 2D system to train a RL agent.

Comment: Vector-to-raster conversion is ancient technology (we had to code half-line scan in FORTRAN, back in the day). Any GIS package should be able to manage it. Please [Edit] your Question to focus on what you tried, and the problem you encountered.